# How do I show the set of all elements of the type $(x+ 4\mathbb{Z}, y+6\mathbb{Z})$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2 | x-y$ is a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've checked there are $12$ elements in the set. $(1 + 4\mathbb{Z},1+6\mathbb{Z})$ appears to be the generator. Is there another way besides with direct computations to show the group is $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$?

I'm asking because I have also other problems to do where a similar set is to turn out to be a cyclic group of order $60$, and it would be easier if I had a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $h:\mathbb{Z}_{12} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6: x \mapsto (x \operatorname{mod} 4, x \operatorname{mod} 6)$. Note that it is a homomorphism. Note that since $ (x \operatorname{mod} 4) - (x \operatorname{mod} 6) = 0 \operatorname{mod} 2$, $h$ maps into the described set. Moreover $h$ is injective: if $(x, y)$ is in the given set then if $x$ is even then so is $y$ so $\exists x', y' $ such that $x = 2x', y=2y'$. By the Chinese remainder theorem there exists a unique  $z <6$ such that $z \operatorname{mod} 2 = x'$ and $z \operatorname{mod} 3 = y'$ and we have $h(2z) = (x,y)$. The same reasoning applies when $x$ (and $y$) is odd. You will always encounter this situation with $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ with as subset the $(x,y)$ with $x-y = 0 \operatorname{mod} \operatorname{gcd}(m, n) $.

Comment: Can you please explain some more, in the end it is not clear what conclusion you make. Thank you.

Comment: Up to what point did you understand my answer? The Chinese theorem point?

Comment: Well, the same situation arises for example with $\mathbb{Z}_10 \times \mathbb{Z}_15$ where $5 | (x-y) $. What group do you get?

Comment: Read $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$  please :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I wasn't clear above when I said that I don't understand. I meant more like what conclusion do you make with your answer in the end? Anyway, I'd like you to correct me if I don't understand you completely: You've defined a homomorphism that is injective and maps only to the subset of $\mathbb{Z_4} \times \mathbb{Z_6}$ with the specific types of elements described above. Therefore restricting the range of $h$ gives an isomorphism with $\mathbb{Z_{12}}$. Correct?

Comment: This is indeed completely correct.